# MySQL Extended Display

Tags: mysql

Is there any equivalent to psql's \x to view a record with each column on a new row?

Answer (score 73):

Append `\G` to the end of the statement instead of the semicolon:

`SELECT * FROM table_name [WHERE condition] \G`

Comment: Huge thanks. I'm a Postgres user at heart, forced to work in a MySQL environment.  This is a feature I always use in Postgres and have been missing.  THANKYOU!!!

Comment: Is it possible to switch extended display on for a session? To avoid having to place it at the end for each query?

Answer (score 0):

For all the results of the session:
Start the session with the "--vertical" parameter.
For query output within a previously started session without --vertical:
Append "\G" to the end of the statement instead of ";" (semicolon).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).