# Display select results vertically in psql, as is done by MySQL's \G

Tags: postgresql, psql

In MySQL, you can terminate a `select` query with `\G` (as opposed to `\g`) to display the results vertically:

```
select * from foo \G

***************
 id: 1
bar: Hello
***************
 id: 2
bar: World
```

How can one do the same thing for PostgreSQL using psql?

Comment: See also http://serverfault.com/a/37260/131498

Comment: And also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604723/alternate-output-format-for-psql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL Extended Display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1794992/mysql-extended-display)

Comment: @amphetamachine not really. That question is the inverse, so depending upon which DB you are familiar with, you'd come at this one or the other way. This question has many more views than that question, so I'd suggest that this resource has more SEO capital for whatever reason than the other answer as well.

Answer (score 275):

You can do this by enabling *Expanded display*.

Toggle this setting via `\x`. For example:

```
# \x
Expanded display is on.
# \x
Expanded display is off.
```

When on, results are shown in tabular (vertical) form:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]
id  | 1
bar | Hello
-[ RECORD 2 ]
id  | 2
bar | World
```

You can run this for a single command by using the `\x\g\x` suffix to toggle expanded display on, run the query, then toggle it off again.

```
select * from foo \x\g\x
```

Or via psql param as shared [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407860/display-select-results-vertically-in-psql-as-is-done-by-mysqls-g#comment86901835_22407861)

```
psql db -xc 'select * from table'
```

Comment: Or use `-x` switch when running non-interactively (`psql db -xc 'select * from foo'`).

Answer (score 1):

Same can be achieved in dbeaver for postgres using "record" option in grid results