# How to query PostgreSQL as list of column name and value instead of table

Tags: postgresql, psql

in MySQL I could display query result as a list, for example:

```
   id : 123
 name : 'test'
 foo  : 'bar'
```

instead of standard result:

```
+----+------+-----+
| id | name | foo |
+----+------+-----+
| 123|test  |bar  |
+----+------+-----+
```

using `select * from tablename \G` in `mysql` command line.

How to do this in PostgreSQL's `psql`?

Comment: You can check you this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22407860/display-select-results-vertically-in-psql-as-is-done-by-mysqls-g

Comment: See the examples in the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html#APP-PSQL-EXAMPLES

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for the expanded output `\x`.

```
regress=> \x
Expanded display is on.
regress=> select * from posts;
-[ RECORD 1 ]---------
id    | 1
title | bork bork bork
-[ RECORD 2 ]---------
id    | 2
title | honkey tonk
```

or maybe `\x\t\a` (extended, tuples-only, unaligned):

```
craig=> \x\t\a
Expanded display is on.
Tuples only is on.
Output format is unaligned.

craig=> select * from posts;
id|1
title|bork bork bork

id|2
title|honkey tonk
```

You may want `\f :` too:

```
craig=> \x\t\a\f :
Expanded display is on.
Tuples only is on.
Output format is unaligned.
Field separator is ":".

craig=> select * from posts;
id:1
title:bork bork bork

id:2
title:honkey tonk
```

---

When I'm invoking `psql` from a script, I tend to use:

```
psql -qAt
```

often with the `-0` option, too, so it emits null bytes as record separators so fields with embedded newlines are more easily handled.